# Issue with using javascript plugin with input array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple text input using the timepicki jquery plugin. I am able successfully use the plugin on my first text input, but I am not able to use it on the additional inputs created by array as shown.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID


var x = 1; //initlal text box count

$('#timepicker').timepicki(); //Call Timepicki plugin for #timepicker ID
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
e.preventDefault();
if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
x++; //text box increment
$(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="timepicker[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
}
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
})
});
</script>

<html>
Ring Time:
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" id='timepicker' type='text'name='timepicker[]'"></div>
</div><br><br>
</html>
```

My question is - How can can enable it so that all instances of the timepicker input can use the timepicker plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: You would need to attach the plugin to each new input after you create them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a couple of changes that should make it work

```
$('.timepicker').timepicki(); //class instead of id
```

and in your HTML and javascript

```
<input type="text" class="timepicker" name="timepicker[]" />
```

in the click function

```
 $(add_button).click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 if(x < max_fields){
 x++;
 $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" class="timepicker" name="timepicker[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
 }
 $('.timepicker').timepicki();
 });
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks! I'm still learning JS. Its alot different from PHP and C#.

Comment: No sweat, happy coding!